# .htaccess rewrite rules for Dynamic URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to create url rewrite rule for my dynamic website using `.htaccess` file from:

```
http://localhost/pincode/pinpo.php?po=Ameda
```

to:

```
http://localhost/pincode/postoffice/Ameda.php
```

How to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your `pincode/.htaccess` file

```
   RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /pincode/
RewriteRule ^postoffice/(.*)\.php$ /pincode/pinpo.php?po=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of server the process is reverse, it rewrites your forged static url to dynamic url that works to retrieve the dynamic content.

Your url in your website (request_uri) should be

http://localhost/pincode/postoffice/Ameda.php

And you .htaccess file in the webroot should contain:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^pincode/postoffice/(.*)\.php$ /pincode/pinpo.php?po=$1 [L]
```

In case you want to rewrite dynamic to look static, you still need two rewrite rules in order your dynamic data retrieval works, this way:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /                                
    #static to dynamic, with nol arg to prevent infinite looping    
    RewriteRule ^pincode/postoffice/([a-z0-9]+).php$ pincode/pinpo.php?nol&po=$1 [L]
    #dynamic to static:
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^po=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
    RewriteRule ^/pincode/pinpo.php$ pincode/postoffice/%1.php [L]
```